# Trouble with the for loop (Beginner)

Tags: c++, vector

I am starting to learn c++, and I got this simple program:
(I apologize in advance for my english)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<double> time_vector(int interval[], float increment)
{
    vector<double> time; 
    for (double i=interval[0]; i<=interval[1]; i=i+increment)
        time.push_back(i);
    return time;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int interval[] = {0,3};
    float increment = 0.1;
    vector<double> time = time_vector(interval, increment);

    for (vector<double>::iterator it=time.begin(); it!=time.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is of the time_vector function is to create a vector that ranges [a,b], and increments itself by an increment value. This would mimic the command from matlab

```
a:increment:b
```

But when I run it, I get this:

```
0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2 2.1 2.2        2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 0
```

As you can see the last element is not a 3.0, as it should. Am I doing the right way?

Comment: As `time_vector` doesn't modify `interval`, you can make the parameter `const interval[]` to avoid mistakes. However, as there are only 2 values, I would suggest you just pass 2 int paremters.

Comment: Not sure where the 0 at the end came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue regards [internal floating point representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point): in the last cycle of your for loop this is what might happen

```
i = 2.9000000432133675
increment = 0.100000001

i + increment = 3.0000000442133675
```

Thus the condition is no more met and you won't have the last expected result stored.

You might want to add an epsilon value to your results to ensure correctness, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define EPSILON 0.0000001

vector<double> time_vector(int interval[], float increment)
{
    vector<double> time; 
    for (double i=interval[0]; i<=interval[1] + EPSILON; i=i+increment)
        time.push_back(i);
    return time;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int interval[] = {0,3};
    float increment = 0.1f;
    vector<double> time = time_vector(interval, increment);

    for (vector<double>::iterator it=time.begin(); it!=time.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/WRi2ln

Nb. this doesn't mean C++ is *less precise than Matlab*. Matlab internally deals with all these sort of tricks and tradeoffs but just makes it opaque to you and let you concentrate on other things (C++ allows you to do more low-level stuff, but this is the price you pay for it).

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Also the other answers helped me. But one thing that I am wondering, would this be the right way of writing the code? or there would be a better way of handling this problem? As another guy already said, I am using a lot of implicit casting. Is this a problem in c++?

Comment: I would agree: if you have no explicit need on the function signature I'd recommend avoiding unnecessary casts. Usually on x86 systems int2double is handled with specific instructions (e.g. [CVTSI2SD](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_58.html) ) but these also have a cost. If you can, avoid it.

Comment: Finally: the epsilon I put there was intended to be an example, if possible rely on machine epsilon (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/) for floating point values or do an integer loop and add the increment times the index to a floating point base value (i.e. avoid floating point roundoff accumulation and perhaps perform less casts.. especially float to ints on x86)

Answer (score 4):

Very probably a floating point precision issue. See [floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) (What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic)

So `0.1` is not *exactly* representable in [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

PS. It is not a C++ issue per se. You'll get the same issue in C, Ada, or Fortran.

Answer (score 1):

Due to floating point representation and the way you have structured your loop, there is no guarantee that the last number in range in be present in vector. One way to avoid this is to compute desired number of steps to generate desired range and perform computations, like this:

```
std::vector<double> time_vector(int interval[], float increment)
{
    std::vector<double> time; 
    int nSteps = (int)((interval[1] - interval[0]) / increment + 0.5f); //Rounding

    time.push_back(interval[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i <= nSteps; ++i)
    {
        time.push_back(interval[0] + i * increment);
    }
    return time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you're doing a lot of implicit casts between double, float, and int.  Instead of storing the interval as two ints, try storing it as a float, you're also incrementing the values in the time vector by a float, though they are stored as doubles.  Try using a uniform type so there are list implicit conversions:

```
vector<float> time_vector(float interval[], float increment)
{
    vector<float> time; 
    for (float i=interval[0]; i<=interval[1]; i=i+increment)
        time.push_back(i);
    return time;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float interval[] = {0,3};
    float increment = 0.1;
    vector<float> time = time_vector(interval, increment);

    for (vector<float>::iterator it=time.begin(); it!=time.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, floating point sum is not what you expect!

Comment: The output is correct for me after compiling with gcc.

Comment: That being said, I understand the issues re: floating point arithmetic.  Just suggesting the OP could try this as well.